# Invalid password 13.0

Tags: 13.04

I had installed 64 bit Ubuntu 13.04 on my desktop. For first two login It accept my password but from today system can not accept my password. I had not changed the password. Please suggest solution to recover password.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link will definitely help you out

[How to recover ubuntu password](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/03/unlock-the-root-account-reset-the-root-password-change-username-in-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail/)